# How to disable pencil redraw in Adobe Illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, pencil

I can't draw arrow with a pencil in Illustrator. First I draw a half

[image]

and then I draw a side line, but when I connect it to the main body, Illustrator redraws it to make continuous line

[image]

How to disable this "feature"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Double click the Pencil Tool, and in the tool options uncheck "Edit selected paths".

[image]